# Where is $title set in drupal views files?

Tags: drupal, drupal-6, drupal-views

I am working on a drupal 6 site and I am dealing with a views template file which overrides views-view-table.tpl.php. The first few lines of code are:

```
<table class="<?php print $class; ?>">
<?php if (!empty($title)) : ?>
<caption><?php print $title; ?></caption>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Where is $title set and what is it? It doesn't seem to be the node id. In the site I am working one, its displaying one of the fields!

Answer (score 1):

It's the title of the View Display (not the machine name of the View!)
See left top corner of the Views Admin UI.